# ASP.NET & Ajax - How to pass value from ajax to action?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a few checkboxes on my page. I have some jquery in place to ensure that only one checkbox is checked at a time. I have assigned a specific value to each checkbox. The below ajax finds the checkbox that is checked and I'm grabbing the value associated to it. How do I pass that value to my action?

AJAX

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function () {            
        var PaymentID = document.querySelector('#chkBox:checked').value;
        alert(PaymentID);   // for test         
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: PaymentID,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "@Url.Action("MyAction", "Home")",  
            success: function () {
                return PaymentID; // Failed attempt at passing data. 
            }
        })
    })
```

Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyAction(string PaymentID)
    {
        // Magic
    }
```

Please keep in mind i am fairly new to ajax. Thx guys.

Comment: If you only want one checked at a time, you should consider using radio buttons, not checkboxes

Comment: checkboxes give me the ability to unselect a specific item. i have jquery in place that ensures only one is checked at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a javascript object with name `PaymentID` ( *same name as your action method parameter*)

```
 data: { PaymentID: PaymentID },
```

You do not need to specify `contentType` as you are sending a simply object. Also you do not necessarily need to specify dataType for your ajax call to send the data.

This should work.

```
var PaymentID = "some value";
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",              
            data: { PaymentID: PaymentID },            
            url: "@Url.Action("MyAction", "Home")",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log('response', response);
            }
        });
```

Or you can use the `$.post` method.

```
$.post("@Url.Action("MyAction", "Home")",{ PaymentID: PaymentID }, function(response) {
      console.log('response', response);
});
```

Comment: This lead me to my answer. Thanks.